# SQL Insert multiple value to one key staff from two tables (try to improve)

Tags: sql

Basically, I want to insert multiple values to a signal staff form two tables, `Value_table` and `Staff_table`, which look like this:

**Staff_table**

```
|      staff_num      |     staff_name   |     staff_role   |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          1          |         Bill     |         1        |
|          2          |         James    |         1        |
|          3          |         Gina     |         2        |
|          4          |         Tim      |         3        |
```

**Value_table**

```
|       value      |    value_name    |    value_state   |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|         123      |         Food     |         0        |
|         476      |         Drink    |         1        |
|         656      |         Dinner   |         1        |
|          77      |         Phone    |         1        |
```

And the result should look like this:

```
|      staff_num      |       value      |
+---------------------+------------------+
|          1          |         123      |
|          1          |         476      |
|          1          |         656      |
|          1          |         77       |
|          2          |         123      |
|          2          |         476      |
|          2          |         656      |
|          2          |         77       |
.
.
.
.
```

I find a SQL way to do it which is the following code.

```
INSERT INTO Result_table
    SELECT DISTINCT a.staff_code, c.func_num 
    FROM Staff_table a 
    JOIN Value_table c ON c.value BETWEEN 0 AND 656;
```

It works but I don't think the last line

```
JOIN Value_table c ON c.value BETWEEN 0 AND 656;
```

is a good way to select all the value from the table.

Is there a better way to do it in SQL?

Comment: No relationship. Try cross join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you may use `CROSS JOIN` as

```
INSERT INTO Result_table
SELECT distinct a.staff_code,c.func_num 
  FROM Staff_table a 
 CROSS JOIN Value_table c
```

*Since, there's no need to restrict the value column which is already between 0 and 656 depending on the sample data.*

**Edit :** If you want to restrict add a `WHERE` condition below as

```
INSERT INTO Result_table
SELECT distinct a.staff_code,c.func_num 
  FROM Staff_table a 
 CROSS JOIN Value_table c
 WHERE c.value BETWEEN 77 and 123
```

Comment: then what if I want some restrict?
Like only value 123 and 77 add in all staff.